# Table in kivy how to change value when i click on field

Tags: python, kivy

Hi gyus  please tell me  somone how when i click on field i can  change value in table and is it possible? 
I mean this table

my code so i want to change value in single rows when i clicked it:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable
from kivy.metrics import dp

from kivy.uix.button import Button


class DemoApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        screen = Screen()
        data_table = MDDataTable(pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5},
                                 size_hint=(1, 1),
                                 #rows_num=10,
                                 column_data=[
                                     ("field.", dp(50)),
                                     ("field", dp(50)),
                                     ("field", dp(50))
                                     
                                 ],
                                 row_data=[
                                     ("field", "field", "field"),
                                     ("field", "field", "field"),
                                     ("field", "field", "field"),
                                     ("field", "field", "field"),
                                     ("field", "field", "field"),
                                     ("field", "field", "field"),
                                     ("field", "field", "field"),
                                     ("field", "field", "field")

                                 ]
                                 )
        
        screen.add_widget(data_table)
        return screen




DemoApp().run()
```

[image]

Comment: Post a minimal runnable example

Comment: @Neizvestnyjlook right now i  added my code

Comment: Do you want to do something like Excel?

Comment: yeah i want it ..